# VB2010 How can i clear cookies webbrowser with button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

VB2010  How can i clear cookies webbrowser with button ?

I created my webbrowser on vb2010 but i have problem; how can i clear Webbrowser cookies & cache? Its been answered 1k times but i still didn't find working solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do this before you actually run the web browser.

Temporary Internet Files

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8")
```

Cookies

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2")
```

History

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you for answers Jacooobley.Now I have this error. Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies' is denied.

Comment: Ah. Are you on your own computer or a company one? I've updated answer, try this instead

Comment: Thanks you for help , that is my computer but i still coulnd't clear cookie my app.meanwhile I am doing Facebook auto login webbrowser on vb2010. I still searching solve on web.