# Delete Webbrowser1 cookies And Cache .net

Tags: .net, cookies, webbrowser-control, browser-history

i tried to delete My Webbrowser1 History with Login cookies Cache history (Facebook)

and i cant delete login Info,

i want every loading Webbrowser1 in app start up will required login not loading my previous login info from (Facebook).

here my failed with 4 methods. ^^

-1

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie = ""
```

-2

```
WebBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

-3

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")
```

-4

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8")
```

i tried those 4 Methods, Without any luck to work, any idea !

And as everytime, please don't press " this question not useful" ^^.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB2010 How can i clear cookies webbrowser with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997161/vb2010-how-can-i-clear-cookies-webbrowser-with-button)

Comment: @VisualVincent Big ty i figure it out before, you are the best.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just voted to close it as a duplicate of that question because that's what you should do if a post has already been answered elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved from another thread :

[VB2010 How can i clear cookies webbrowser with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997161/vb2010-how-can-i-clear-cookies-webbrowser-with-button)

Clear Cookies,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2")
```